# Skaffold to deploy an existing image already built

Tags: skaffold

I have a use case where I build the image once using Github Actions to Github container repository. I would then like to use Skaffold to deploy that image already built to multiple Kubernetes clusters. The build and deploy need to be separate so we don't use Skaffold to build but to only to deploy.

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta4
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: svc-one
build:
  local:
    push: true
    useDockerCLI: true
  artifacts:
    - image: registry.digitalocean.com/xyz/svc-one
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile <-- instead of this use existing built image from github

deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a build section in your `skaffold.yaml` if you don't want to build. Just update the image in that manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment and just to clarify what user140547 is saying. In your skaffold.yaml file it now looks like this

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta4
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: svc-one

deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/deployment.yaml
```

Then in your deployment.yaml file you just have to include the image name

```
spec:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: (yourImageNamefromGitHubOrWherever)
```